# Application listed at snapcraft but cannot be found by 'snap install'

Tags: 22.04, kubuntu, snap, 64-bit, snap-store

[image]

When an [application](https://snapcraft.io/redplayer) is listed at snapcraft I expect `snap install` to be able to find it.

```
~$ snap find redplayer
Name       Version  Publisher  Notes  Summary
redplayer  3.1.6    edsonk     -      Player de gerenciamento de conteúdo de tv.
```

but:

```
~$ sudo snap install redplayer
error: snap "redplayer" not found
```

Comment: Silly question, but which architecture are you trying to install RedPlayer on? I see the snap is available for `amd64` and `armhf`. Based on the tags, I'm *assuming* you're using `amd64`, but it would be good to confirm 

Comment: @matigo - amd64 it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be that the creator of that snap has blocked your region/country ... Please see this related post about another snap https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/freecad-snap-mia/22040/1 .

Actually, some Geo-locatin based service seems to be used on their website ... Check https://redberry.com.br/planos ... and if it says "Nenhum plano disponível para você." then it means "No plans for you" ... Note this is not based on solid science but rather on my assumption.

Specifying allowed install regions and excluding others is possible and doable for snap creators/publishers ... However, on the user side, there is not yet a `snap` based method to know if that is configured and there is not even an informative error message that will clearly show that.

However, the GUI desktop snap-store app will refuse to show that snap's details/installation page although it will appear in the search, but clicking on it will show a blank page ... So, that might be a sign.

Comment: It does say "no plan for you" ... I was interested in the app for the chromecast feature, no idea why that would be region-restricted etc. Enough for me to become totally un-interested in their app and website now, but I think no such dead stuff should be seen on the snap store.

Comment: @Raffa: do you have any links to snapcraft.io holding information about geoblocking for snaps. Would be interesting to read Canonical's documentation on this.

Comment: @noisefloor When I search for that on google, it takes me back here :D ... That's when I thought there might not be any easy to find resources for that, but [Releasing your app](https://snapcraft.io/docs/releasing-your-app) and [Create a developer account](https://snapcraft.io/docs/creating-your-developer-account) is a good place to start.

Answer (score -1):

When trying to install an application via snapcraft.io, a) the application has to be available there and b) it has the be available for your given CPU architecture. The search is unfortunately not architecture-sensitive, which means it searches by name only.

The available architectures can be found on snapcraft.io/name_of_the_snap when clicking on the field stating the current version in the upper right corner and then selecting *"Show architecture"*. A pull-down menu will open showing for which architectures the snap is available.

While this is the case for many / most snaps for AMD64 (=the common CPU architecture for PCs using AMD/Intel CPUs), it may not be the case for armhf (e.g. used by older models of the Rasperry Pi) and arm64 (e.g. used by newer models of the Raspberry Pi).

Comment: That app is available for amd64 and so am I.